# Apache Reverse Proxy | Mixed Active Content has been blocked from loading in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, apache, reverse-proxy

I have configured a Reverse Proxy to be able to supply the demand of my clients for having VPS and being able to host their websites, a new problem that has come to me is that when a client is going to install a WordPress for some reason the contents of styles and scripts load them by HTTP and not by HTTPS so the browsers block it, this only happens to me with the VPS that have WordPress, others that have pure programmed websites either in HTML, CSS, JS, REACT, Laravel, PHP does not happen.

Configuration of the .conf in the Reverse Proxy

> http_proxy.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domain.com
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.119/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.119/
</VirtualHost>
```

> https_proxy.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName domain.com
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.119/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.119/
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem
  Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Configuration of the .conf in the Destination Host:

> https_domain.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost  192.168.1.119:443>
  ServerName domain.com
  ServerAdmin suport@domain.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com

  SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem
  Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

> http_domain.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost  192.168.1.119:80>
  ServerName domain.com
  ServerAdmin suport@domain.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com
</VirtualHost>
```